# vscode test explorer cannot run single test, but works for full test class

Tags: visual-studio-code, phpunit, test-explorer

Since about 2 month I cannot execute a phpunit test individually - only the full class (using the vscode test explorer).

This is my setting in vscode for my test files

```
{test,tests,Test,Tests}\**\*Test.php
```

When I click run in the test explorer (see picture)

[image: Run Test individually]

I get the following output

[image: Output after single Test]

However, clicking run on the full class works

[image: Success on full class run]

Answer (score 0):

The full explanation can be found here: https://github.com/recca0120/vscode-phpunit/issues/64

The basic work around is to downgrade to version `2.0.72`

It seems that a change in the used regex (`/^.*::testCallAndRequestIsAjax.*$/`) is causing this issue in the most recent version.

Downgrade by

- going to extensions
- right click PHPUnit Test Explorer
- install another version
- chose 2.0.72